# Sorting list in a pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently have a list named items. I used `items.sort()` to get them in ascending order but I want the desired output. Is there any simple yet easy way to do it in python?

```
items = ['hat1', 'mat3', 'bat2', 'bat1', 'hat2', 'mat4', 'hat5', 'hat6', 'mat1']
```

Current O/P-

```
bat1, bat2, hat1, hat2, hat5, hat6, mat1, mat3, mat4
```

Desired O/P-

```
bat1, bat2
hat1, hat2, hat5, hat6
mat1, mat3, mat4
```

Comment: Is the output a list of lists? Is it sorted lexicographically?

Comment: with items.sort(), yes in alphabetical order

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

items = ['hat1', 'mat3', 'bat2', 'bat1', 'hat2', 'mat4', 'hat5', 'hat6', 'mat1']

for k, g in groupby(sorted(items), key=lambda x: x[:3]):
    print(list(g))

# ['bat1', 'bat2']
# ['hat1', 'hat2', 'hat5', 'hat6']
# ['mat1', 'mat3', 'mat4']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it as a whole list, `sorted` can work:

```
sorted(items, key=lambda x:(x[:3], int(x[-1])))
```

Output:

```
['bat1', 'bat2', 'hat1', 'hat2', 'hat5', 'hat6', 'mat1', 'mat3', 'mat4']
```

Comment: That output can be obtained with just `sorted(items)` and is same as OP currently has. What he wants more is to group them.